# How did Hercule Poirot grow a moustache?

Tags: plot-explanation, death-on-the-nile-2022

In murder mystery [Death on the Nile (2022)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7657566/) we learn that,

Hercule Poirot has been a World War I veteran and suffered facial injury which spans from left face via under the nose to a little part on right cheek.

[image]

His lover, nurse Katherine, suggests he grow a mustache to hide his scars. To which he has grown a full stylish moustache.

[image]

Now we know from recent research that [hairs can be grown on wounded parts of body.](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/11/181128082747.htm) But in 1914 during which Hercule Poirot suffered injury it was not possible through clinical methods.

So, how could Hercule Poirot had grown a full moustache in-spite of an injury?

Comment: This happens when modern writers try to explain things, that didn't need an explanation

Comment: @Paulie_D Agreed, but it does have relation to character development and moustache is what makes him look unique.

Answer (score 3):

### Quite simply, because that's what Branagh wanted.

> During their conversation, he turns to face her, revealing that his face is disfigured. To her credit, Katherine takes the disturbing sight of Poirot's wound in stride, telling him that, in order to cover it up, he should grow a mustache.
>
> Indeed, the mustache worn by Branagh's Poirot manages to completely cover his war wound. In his career as a detective, Poirot's chief flaw is his egotistical vanity; he's the best at what he does, and he knows it. His impeccably maintained mustache represents his narcissism, but it also literally covers up his biggest flaw — the battle scars that define his first, and greatest, failure.
>
> It's worth noting that none of this characterization was part of Agatha Christie's original vision of Poirot, who never served in WWI or suffered facial scars — it's all the creation of the "Death on the Nile" filmmakers. **Kenneth Branagh told Parade that it's attempt to more deeply characterize Poirot while contextualizing his most famous physical trait: that très chic facial hair**.

[[Source]](https://www.looper.com/761343/poirots-mustache-in-death-on-the-nile-is-more-important-than-you-think/)